# TR/// : How do you apply TR to a string?

Tags: raku

With `tr///`, I can do this:

```
my $str = 'xABCz';
$str ~~ tr:c/ABC//;

say "-->{$str}<--";

--output:--
-->ABC<--
```

But with `TR///`, which creates a new string, there doesn't seem to be a way to apply it directly to a string:

```
my $str = 'xABCz';
$str ~~ tr:c/ABC//;

my $new_str = $str ~~ TR:c:d/ABC//;
say "-->{$new_str}<--";

--output:--
-->True<--
```

I can use `with` to set `$_` to `$str`:

```
my $str = 'xABCz';

with $str {   # now $_ refers to $str
    my $new_str = TR:c:d/ABC//;  # TR/// is called on $_.
    say "-->{$new_str}<--";
} 

--output:--
-->ABC<--
```

...or even:

```
my $str = 'xABCz';
my $new_str = TR:c:d/ABC// with $str;

say "-->{$new_str}<--";

--output:--
-->ABC<--
```

In perl, I would write:

```
my $str = 'xABCz';
my $new_str = $str =~ tr/ABC//rcd;  #r - new_string, c - complement, d - delete
say $new_str;

-output:--
ABC
```

Comment: cf [rakudo issue #1551](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1551).

Comment: FYI, you can overwrite your original `$str` with: `$str = TR:c:d/ABC// given $str;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Str.trans`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/trans) should have the same effect non-destructively.

```
my $new_str = $str.trans("ABC" => "")
```

Comment: ...so in my case: `$new_str = $str.trans('ABC' => '', :c, :d);`

Comment: Actually, in this case the `:d` is unnecessary because of the way trans() repeats the replacement characters if there are more characters in the match. For instance: `'ABCDE'.trans('ABCD' => 'xy')` outputs `xyxyE`. On the other hand, adding the :d option will delete any match characters for which there is not a corresponding replacement character: `'ABCDE'.trans('ABCD' => 'xy', :d)` outputs `xyE`.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a valid way to use `TR` with `~~`; `TR` must always operate on the topic variable (e.g., set with `with`). `TR` is the transliteration equivalent of `S` (nondestructive substitution), and [the docs for `S`](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#S///_non-destructive_substitution) note that:

> Note: since the result is obtained as a return value, using this operator with the `~~` smartmatch operator is a mistake and will issue a warning. To execute the substitution on a variable that isn't the `$_` this operator uses, alias it to `$_` with `given`, `with`, or any other way. Alternatively, use the `.subst` method.

Similarly,, using `TR` with `~~` is a mistake (and, as @raiph noted above, [probably should issue a warning](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1551)). You should instead set `$_` using `given`/etc or use the `.trans` method.

Answer (score 1):

*Not sure if I have a 'rule of thumb' about this yet, but one might consider using `s///` and `tr///` only with the `sed`-like `-pe` command-line flags (and/or the `~~` smart-matcher, as the OP has illustrated). For all other cases, use `S///` and `TR///`, setting the topic (e.g. with `given`) as necessary:*

```perl
#Below works:

~$ raku -pe 's:g/\,/\t/;' file.csv

#OR

~$ raku -pe 'tr/,/\t/;' file.csv
```

Where this gets confusing is that `sed`, as a "stream-editor", picks the value out of the stream, modifies it, and puts ("returns") the value back to the stream for you. Short and sweet--but quite different from `awk` or practically any other dynamic language you might be playing with.

To accomplish the same task with `awk` and many other languages, you need an explicit out`put` statement with ***mutable strings***. Here's where the ***"big-S"*** and a ***"big-TR"*** notations really shine (note the `-ne` non-autoprinting, `awk`-like command-line flags):

```perl
#Below works:

~$ raku -ne 'S:g/\,/\t/.put;'  file.csv

#OR 

~$ raku -ne 'TR/,/\t/.put;'  file.csv
```

So this may seem arcane if you're not writing one-liners, but you can simply remember from above: reading `lines()` from a file will require the ***"big-S"*** or ***"big-TR"*** notations like in the second (`awk`-like case), as opposed to the first `sed`-like case:

```perl
#Below with tr/// doesn't work:

~$ raku -e 'for lines() {tr/,/\t/.put};'  file.csv > file.tsv
Cannot modify an immutable Str (input,file,text,here...)
  in block <unit> at -e line 1

#Below with TR/// works as desired:

~$ raku -e 'for lines() {TR/,/\t/.put};'  file.csv > file.tsv
```

(Finally, you should be aware that Raku did away with `-i` "in-place" editing of files. I have only anecdotal evidence for the following reasoning, but some SO comments have suggested that Perl end-users were accidentally "emptying" their input files with the wrong combination of command-line flags and "small-s" or "small-tr" operators. Hence the introduction of ***"big-S"*** or ***"big-TR"*** notations, which are inherently safer).

Comment: FYI, this @BradGilbert comment suggests that `S///` is the Raku replacement for Perl's `s///r`: https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.users/2019/06/msg6777.html